# Using Stacks to pop and push a method or action

Tags: java, data-structures, stack

So for a project for Uni I have a LinkedList with methods such as insert, delete, sort, reverse, etc. Part of the assignment is the implementation of an Undo button using Stacks.

is to have it so that every time i call a method, i push it's counter. For example I insert something, so i push a delete of that something. However I'm not sure if you can do that with a stack? If I understand stacks correctly aren't they primitive data types in an Array?

Sorry if the answer is obvious, but I really did do research on this and am still quite blank on the answer so any help is super appreciated!

Comment: Please mark your question as answered if it was answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This is a stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_%28abstract_data_type%29). Your assingment seems to follow the [Command Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern). So you would "record" each action (like `add`, `delete`, ...) in a LIFO (Last In - First Out)-stack. When you undo an action, you simply "reverse" the topmost command of the stack. How to "reverse" the operation exactly depends on the operation in question and is for you to figure out.

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by "record"? If a stack holds a object I don't understand how it can record an action like you say.

Comment: You need data, which represents the action. Take a look at the Command Pattern link. It provides a Java example.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing some aspects of a stack data structure.

A stack is a last in, first out. What this means is that you have some root Node that contains whatever the data type you need to hold is, and then a reference to the next Node. So for the last in, you would go to the very last Node in your linked list, and add it at the end. For removing, you would find the last Node, and remove the reference to it from the previous.

I don't think you've done enough research then, read up on linked lists, and the data structure stack. If you have any more questions, please ask, but try to find the answers yourself first.